# How to remove "You're reviewing:" text?

Tags: magento2, review

Using default **LUMA theme** and extended it for custom changes .

There is **text in review** form on product page:  " **You're reviewing:** " .

How can I **change it** or **remove it** from review form?

Don't tell `hiding via CSS` , Kindly help me **removing or changing** it via `code`

any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: extend your review module

Comment: couldn't get the file where to change

Comment: turn on debug mode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy `form.phtml` from below location

```
/vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml
```

Place at below location ,copy  only  required file do not copy whole module.

```
/app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Review/templates/form.phtml
```

in this file you will find below code on line no 21

```
<span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __("You're reviewing:"); ?></span>
```

you can **comment above line** or you can alter the text in it.

**Keep your cache disabled**

Comment: sure , let me know if any problem

Comment: could you please check this and help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/195703/56319

Answer (score 2):

You have to override below file of review module-

```
/your_magento/vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml
```

you can find **You're reviewing:**  . text on line 21

Comment: could you please check this and help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/195703/56319